# What type of database replication should I use?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, replication

I have 2 databases, one on local server and one on a remote server.

I created a transactional replication publication on the local DB, which feeds the remote DB every minute with whatever updates it gets. So far, this is working perfectly.

However, the local DB needs to get cleaned (all its information deleted) daily. THIS is the part I'm having trouble with, I was expecting a replication mode that would only feed the server DB with the inserts, and make it ignore the part when the local DB gets cleaned. At the moment, the remote DB is also getting cleaned.

Would a different kind of replication help me achieve what I want, or is replication no longer the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987531/sql-server-replication-without-deletes)

Comment: Following the link I found the answer which worked excellent for me. I was kinda looking for people's opinions but this time a link was enough, thanks.